# FltSendMessage: Failed to send messages

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I'm trying to send messages to an application using functions fltkernel.h. I tried several changes but could not make it work.

**in the driver**

```
   X.QuadPart = ((-1 * 10) * 1000) * 1000;  
   message.MessageId = 15;
   message.ReplyLength = 12;
   if NT_SUCCESS( FltSendMessage(fileManager.pFilter, &fileManager.ClientPort, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL/*&Reply*/, NULL/*&ReplyLength*/, &X) );
     DbgPrint("Success!");
```

**in App**

```
  HRESULT hResult = S_OK;
  HANDLE Port;
  FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER message;
  OVERLAPPED Ovlp;

    hResult = FilterConnectCommunicationPort(FLPORTNAME, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, &Port);

    message.MessageId = 0;
    message.ReplyLength = 0;

    while (true){
      hResult = FilterGetMessage(Port, &message, sizeof(FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER), NULL);//&Ovlp
      printf("MessageId %d %d \n", message.MessageId, hResult);
    }
```

**Results**

**DebugView = Success!**
**App Output = MessageId 0 0**

Anyone with any tips?

Comment: Your driver might be getting `STATUS_TIMEOUT` which is a success code, so `NT_SUCCESS()` will evaluate to TRUE. Ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544378(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for the help! I researched more and found that filtergetmessage function receives the data in the following format: OVERLAP FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER BUFFER_STRUCT the size of the receive data buffer must contain the sum of the size of 3 structures